# How can you round down to a given number of decimal places in Perl

Tags: perl, floating-point

I'd like to round down to *N* decimal places (two places for cents). For example

```
5.0166 => 5.01
0.933  => 0.93
```

`sprintf` rounds to the nearest digit so doesn't produce what I want. For example

```
sprintf("%.2f", 5.0166) => 5.02
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use POSIX::floor (http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html):

```
use POSIX;
$original = 5.0166;
$rounded = POSIX::floor($original*100)/100;
print "$rounded\n";
```

If you deal with negative numbers and you'd rather round towards zero rather than rounding down, then use:

```
$rounded = ($original < 0)?(POSIX::ceil($original*100)/100)
                          :(POSIX::floor($original*100)/100);
```

or just

```
$rounded = int($original*100)/100;
```

Comment: `($original < 0)?(POSIX::ceil($original*100)/100):(POSIX::floor($original*100)/100)` is generally known as `int($original)`

Comment: @Borodin - well, `int($original*100)/100`, anyway.

Comment: @JimDavis: Yes, thanks. I did some tests to ensure I was correct at the boundaries too and forgot the original intent in the process

Answer (score 2):

You can mess with a call to [`int`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html) together with multiplication and division to shift the decimal point back and forth, or you can use a string substitution, as shown below, which will work for anything less than 1E15 and greater than 1E-4

This will work

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

for (5.0166, 0.933) {
  say s/\.\d\d\K.+//r;
}
```

**output**

```
5.01
0.93
```

Answer (score 0):

Using more lines to show the steps.

```
$x=5.0166;
$y=int($x*100);
$y=$y/100;
print "$y\n";
```